# Bad operand type for binary operator + first type int[] and second type int

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am trying to access the value of the 2D matrix defines using the 1D array mapping and want to store that specific index value in a variable.

The matrix contains the integer values, on using the concept of 2D matrix to 1D array mapping i am getting the error of "Bad Operand Type for Binary Operator + first type int[] and second type int"

The statement in which the error is cause is:

```
D = fill[ (i-1) * seq_2.length + (j-1)]
```

I am trying to access diagnol value in the matrix fill i.e., fill[i-1][j-1] and wants to store it in a variable D seq_2.length is the size of the columns in the matrix.

the Code is

```
for (i = 1; i <= (seq_1.length); i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= (seq_2.length); j++) {            

        D = fill[ (i-1) * seq_2.length + (j-1)];

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `fill` and what is `D` ... please consider providing enough information

Comment: `(i - 1) * seq_2.length` isn't an `int[]`; so I don't believe that error matches with the statement you have highlighted.

Comment: @Yahya Fill is a 2D Matrix with the values and D is an integer variable to store the value of the diagnol in the 2D matrix

Comment: The 1st row and 1st column of the matrix Fill is initialized with some values, before computing the values for diagnol.

Comment: @Yahya fill is the 2D Matrix with 1st row and 1st column having some values before starting the computation of any type, while D is the integer variable to store the value of the diagnol in the 2D matrix in the variable for further computation

Comment: @OmaidGhayyur if `fill` is 2D array you cannot assign the first dimension to integer because each dimension is an array.

Comment: @Yahya if i first map the Fill 2D matrix to array and then use that array for the computation then the issue is not faced, it is only face when directly try to 2D matrix Fill as mentioned in the question

Answer (score 1):

You're saying that `fill` is 2D array of type `int`, and `D`is a primitive type integer... you're getting the error `Bad Operand Type for Binary Operator + first type int[] and second type int` because you're trying to assign the first dimension of the `fill` 2D array to a primitive data type int.. consider this example:

```
int[][] array = {{1,2},{3,4}}; // 2D array of type int as an example
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
            System.out.println(array[i]); // this basically is getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
            for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
                System.out.println(array[j]); 
                System.out.println(array[i][j]);// this prints out the actual value at the index 
            }       
        }       
    }
```

**The Output:**

```
[I@15db9742
[I@15db9742
1
[I@6d06d69c
2
[I@6d06d69c
[I@15db9742
3
[I@6d06d69c
4
```

Furthermore, if you want to calculate the diagonal value of a *square* 2D array, you can do for example:

```
int[][] array = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
int diagonalSum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<3; i++, System.out.println()){
     for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
        System.out.print(array[i][j]+"\t");
        if(j==i){
            diagonalSum+=array[i][j];
        }
     }  
}   
System.out.println("\nDiagonal Value is: " + diagonalSum);
```

**The Output:**

```
1   2   3   
4   5   6   
7   8   9   

Diagonal Value is: 15
```